# Bash script to print contents of json file

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, terminal

I am very new to bash scripting and am trying to add a bash script in my Makefile. I have a `errors.json` file. How do I write a bash script in my Makefile that checks if the file has any contents. If it is not empty then echo the contents of the `error.json` file else finish. Here is the psuedocode below:

```
if [[ !error.json.isEmpty() ]]; then \
     cat error.json; \
     delete the error.json; \
else \
     delete the error.json;
fi
```

Comment: Why do you need to check whether the file is empty?  How could you tell the difference from just printing the file contents unconditionally?

Comment: First, be sure that your makefile is really running `bash`.  By default make invokes `/bin/sh`, not bash: on _some_ systems `/bin/sh` is actually bash but on others it's not.  If you don't want to write your scripting using POSIX sh syntax, add `SHELL := /bin/bash` to your makefile to force it to use bash (in your example above, `[[` is not POSIX-conforming).

Comment: To test if a file is empty just use the `-s` option to test; from the docs: *`-s FILE` True if file exists and is not empty.*  So `test -s error.json && cat error.json; rm -f error.json` will do what you want (this is POSIX conforming so doesn't require bash).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, not all distros have `/bin/sh` set up as a symlink to run `bash`. To force Bash-compatible syntax in your makefile, you must put this line near the top:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
```

Short answer: you don't have to check if the file is empty or doesn't exist. Just silence the error if the file doesn't exist:

```bash
display-errors:
    @cat error.json 2>/dev/null ;\
    rm -f error.json
```

If you wanted to get fancier about it:

```
display-errors:
    @if [[ -s error.json ]]; then \
        cat error.json ;\
    fi ;\
    rm -f error.json
```

Examples here are written as makefile targets. The weird line ending `;\` is there because Make targets assume every line is going to be a separate command. Adding `\` to the end is a signal to Make that the command line continues below. A `;` is added to tell it to separate the commands even though they're executing from the same line.

`@` is simply to prevent Make from echoing the command as it executes.

Also, the tab characters in this answer are intentional; Make requires them.

From bash(1) documentation for `[[ .. ]]` or the `test` built-in:

> `-s file`
>
> True if file exists and has a size greater than zero.

Comment: What does the ```2>/dev/null``` mean?

Comment: `2>/dev/null` is sh-compatible syntax redirecting error messages to the data sink /dev/null. Putting `2>/dev/null` after your command silences error messages.